# scroll beyond maximum vertical position in flex datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, scroll, itemrenderer

I have a situation where I need to show several 1-column DataGrids one beside the other and control them with 1 vertical scroll bar. (the result looks like 1 DataGrid but since I use a variable row height, each "column" can have a different row height on each row.

In order to achieve the required result, I created several grids and stacked them in an HBox (I know I should use spark but I want to retain my styles and my entire application is in Halo). Outside of the HBox, I have a VerticalScrollBar and I'm able to control the grid's scroll position since I extended the DataGrid and added a vertical scroll bar getter.

For simplicity, I've stripped the code to the bare essentials:

```
<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
    <mx:HBox id="viewPort" top="1" right="15" bottom="0" left="1" minWidth="0"
         horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:VScrollBar id="vScrollBar" top="24" right="0" bottom="0" scroll="onScroll(event)" />
</mx:Canvas>

private function populateGrids() : void
{
    var item:Object;

    var maxScrollPosition:Number = 0;
    var dataGrid:CustomDataGrid;
    var dataProvider:Object = {'1':[11,12,13,14,15,16], '2':[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28], '3':[31]};

    viewPort.removeAllChildren();
    for (item in dataProvider) {
        var col:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
        col.headerText = "Grid" + item;
        col.sortable = false;

        dataGrid = new CustomDataGrid();
        viewPort.addChild(dataGrid);

        dataGrid.minWidth = 200;
        dataGrid.percentHeight = 100;
        dataGrid.percentWidth = 100;
        dataGrid.headerHeight = 23;
        dataGrid.selectable = false;
        dataGrid.variableRowHeight = true;
        dataGrid.columns = [col];
        dataGrid.dataProvider = dataProvider[item];
    }

    viewPort.validateNow();
    for (item in dataProvider) {
        dataGrid = (viewPort.getChildAt(int(item)) as CustomDataGrid);
        maxScrollPosition = Math.max(maxScrollPosition, dataGrid.vScrollBar.maxScrollPosition);
    }

    vScrollBar.maxScrollPosition = maxScrollPosition;
    vScrollBar.scrollPosition = 0;

    // need to shut-off the vertical scroller only after the maxScrollPosition is calculated
    // otherwise, it doesn't calculate it ...
    for (item in dataProvider) {
        dataGrid = (viewPort.getChildAt(int(item)) as CustomDataGrid);
        dataGrid.verticalScrollPolicy = "off";
    }
}

private function onScroll(e:ScrollEvent) : void
{
    var grids:Array = viewPort.getChildren();
    for each (var grid:CustomDataGrid in grids) {
        grid.verticalScrollPosition = e.currentTarget.scrollPosition;
    }
}
```

While this does show the grids and scrolls them, the item renderers are not reused correctly (probably due to the verticalScrollPositon which might be larger than the actual maximum scroll position for each grid).

Am I going at it from a wrong position? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?
If not, is there a way to assign a higher-than-max verticalScrollPosition to a DataGrid and have it show a blank cell where no data exists?

I Hope this was coherent enough ...

BTW: I'm using Flex 4.5.1

Comment: It looks like you are extending DataGrid already. Why not extend it further to utilize multiple data providers? Or use the groupedColumns on the AdvanvedDataGrid with an intermediary data format that contains the aggregate data?

Comment: Thanks drkstr1, the DataGrid cannot be suited to this task since I need a variable cell height (as opposed to variable row height). The AdvancedDataGrid sounds interesting but does it support a sporadic rowspan?

Comment: If you mean different cell heights for the same row, I don't believe that is supported in the AdvancedDataGrid.